# Managing Group policy server2k3

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

How can i make a group policy if  i want a folder permission for selected group only. What would be the scrip for this.

Comment: Do you already have a group built?

Comment: what do you mean by group built?.. a group policy?.. sorry, i am just a newbie

Comment: The AD group that you want to have access. Is the domain group for them already built

Comment: i dont have any group policy yet

Comment: oh!. yeah i already have a Global Security Group that i want to have an access to a folder. Yes, domain already built

Comment: oh!. yeah i already have a Global Security Group that i want to have an access to a folder. Yes, domain already bui

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what you need to do it set the ACL at the folder.

Right click the folder, go to properties, then go to the security tab, advanced --> break inheritance from the parent, enable inheritance to the child folders.

For all the groups you do not want to have access, but do now, uncheck that level of access. Do not deny unless the two groups will never be shared.

Add the group domain\groupName

Set the exact access you want them to have. (Full, Modify, Read, Write, etc.).

From a script you can also use icacls in batch or the command prompt.

In Powershell you can use the set-ACL cmdlet.

Comment: Do i really need to create a Group Policies for this? i just want to have a folder permission in a specific Group only.. I already try what you have instructed.  and i have these scenario, user doesn't have access to the folder can access, also when I remove the Administrator to the Security Tab, that is the time when user doesnt have access to the folder CAN'T Access but also the user which i give permission to access the folder, lose its access too.. I am just thinking maybe there's wrong in setting up my Global Sec. Group.. Please give me some idea on this

Comment: This is not a GP, its ACLs on the folders and files. I would leave domain administrators with access too, so you can update the folder and restore / backup etc...

Without knowing your groups, hierarchy and ACLs I can't guess what else is going on. Any information you can add to the original questions?

Comment: I hope this can help us to identify the problem....I created FolderA and set permission for Administrator, Creator Owner, SYSTEM and UserA. I even uncheck the Allow inheritance Permission

UserA should have access to FolderA

UserA can access FolderA as he should.

But when I log in with another User, I can still access the FolderA.

However, when I remove the Administrator, and retain the 3 users (Creator Owner, SYSTEM and UserA) in the folder permissions, UserA cannot access FolderA.

Comment: I actually prefer a setup that only Administrator and specific group can access a particular folder.  but in this case, other groups cant access the folder if i remove the Administrator.  If Administrator will not be removed, all groups can access, even those groups are not permitted to access the folder

Comment: What type of administrator account is this? Domain Administrator?

Comment: Yes. Domain Admin.